# TimeZone discrepancy in mysql and java

Tags: java, mysql, timezone, convert-tz

I have a query in mysql which compares 2 dates like this

```
convert_tz(updatedDate,'+05:30','-05:00') < ?
```

the convert function returns the value of column createddate in US Time. when I run this query in mysql query browser like

```
convert_tz(updatedDate,'+05:30','-05:00') < '2013-04-14 09:30:00'
```

it gives me correct values for example

```
product    count
-------    ------
    A        123
    B        7
```

Now, I am setting this in java using PreparedStatement like this

```
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTimeInMillis()));

                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("=====new Open Tickets Query executed=====");
                System.out.println(pst);
```

the last line prints the whole query and the value set is

```
convert_tz(updatedDate,'+05:30','-05:00') < '2013-04-14 09:30:00'
```

but it gives me different values like this

```
product    count
-------    ------
    A        155
    B        19
```

So, I suspected that it is TimeZone problem I changed my code to

```
end.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTimeInMillis()));

                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("=====new Open Tickets Query executed=====");
                System.out.println(pst);
```

but it still gives same wrong result.

**More info: How I am setting Calendar end variable**

I have a web application which gives me date string "2013-04-14 09:30:00"

```
            DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                Calendar end=Calendar.getInstance();
                end.setTime(df1.parse(endString));
                end.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
                end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                end.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Also, for experiment I tried with java.util.Date object it gives me correct result following is the code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
end.setTime(sdf.parse("2012-10-01 00:00:00"));
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTime()));
```

**UPDATE :-**
If I use a deprecated method the answer is  correct

```
 pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(octDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900,octDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),octDate.get(Calendar.DATE),octDate.get(Calendar.HOUR),octDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),octDate.get(Calendar.SECOND),0));
pst.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900,end.get(Calendar.MONTH),end.get(Calendar.DATE),end.get(Calendar.HOUR),end.get(Calendar.MINUTE),end.get(Calendar.SECOND),0));
```

**UPDATE 2:-**
After the suggestion of first answer I did this

1) executed `SELECT NOW()` in mysql and it returned `'2013-04-22 11:56:08'`

2) executed

```
System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

output : `Mon Apr 22 11:56:25 IST 2013`

means both systems have same timezone

Comment: MySQL's time zone information has no bearing on your problem, since MySQL is not handling the job of parsing the date. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background: A surprisingly common--and big--misconception shared by even brilliant programmers is the notion that stored time stamps (in your database, Date, Calendar, Timestamp, et al) somehow have time zone information. **They do not.**  A time stamp (up until Java 8, anyway) is stored as the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1 Jan 1970 UTC. End of sentence. The only thing setting the time zone does is provide enough information to the computer to convert that time stamp to a human readable format, and vice versa.

Answer: When you suspected that this was a time zone problem, **you were right**. But the code you used to try to verify this also has a problem:

```
end.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTimeInMillis()));
```

That `setTimeZone` statement has **no effect** on the time stored in `end`, because the time has already been set. It would only have had an effect if you stored the time afterwards, and then only if you used one of Calendar's methods which converted the time from a human readable format (and not `setTimeInMillis`).

When you use `getTimeInMillis` to pass the time stamp to your prepared statement, you're retrieving the time stamp directly. Since you're not converting it to a human format, once again the time zone information is ignored.

When you try

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
end.setTime(sdf.parse("2012-10-01 00:00:00"));
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTime()));
```

and

```
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(octDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900,octDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),octDate.get(Calendar.DATE),octDate.get(Calendar.HOUR),octDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),octDate.get(Calendar.SECOND),0));
pst.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900,end.get(Calendar.MONTH),end.get(Calendar.DATE),end.get(Calendar.HOUR),end.get(Calendar.MINUTE),end.get(Calendar.SECOND),0));
```

things **appear** to work because you are now using methods which convert to/from a human readable format, and therefore the specified time zone information is used. However, this is only covering up the real problem. The real issue is that the time was improperly converted when you parsed it from `endString`. That is, the time zone that `endString` was expressed in does not match the time zone set in `df1` at the time the date was parsed.

SHORT ANSWER: before this line:

```
end.setTime(df1.parse(endString));
```

You need to:

- Figure out what time zone the time in `endString` was expressed in.
- Set `df1` and **not** `end` to that same time zone. Since `df1` is the thing that is converting the date from human format, it's that time zone information that's used.

Cheers!

Comment: @Matt Johnson also makes a very good point. In all places where you are converting a time from text, make sure you're using a location based time zone and not an offset ("America/New York" and not "EST").

Answer (score 2):

Which value is returned from your `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()` and from MySQL default time zone?

BTW you can try using an utility like this one to convert datetime across timezones:

```
public Calendar convertDateToServerTimeZone(Date dateTime, String timeZone) {
    Calendar userDefinedTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    userDefinedTime.setTime(dateTime);
    if(!TimeZone.getDefault().getID().equalsIgnoreCase(timeZone)) {
    System.out.println        ("original defined time: " + userDefinedTime.getTime().toString() + " on tz:" + timeZone);
    Calendar quartzStartDate = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    quartzStartDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, userDefinedTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    System.out.println("adapted time for " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID() + ": " + quartzStartDate.getTime().toString());
    return quartzStartDate;
    } else {
    return userDefinedTime;
    }
}
```

I have worked with this function here: [Java Quartz-Scheduler across TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273917/java-quartz-scheduler-across-timezone)

Hope his helps.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem of timezone  here. because when I use a deprecated method it works fine. when I put dates directly in query the result is correct.

Comment: I don't think MySQL's time zone is the problem. MySQL's time zone information is only used when it handles the job of converting the time from/to text. Since Bhavik is passing the time as a parameter in a prepared statement, it has already been converted. If Bhavik had placed the time as text directly in the query, then MySQL's zone information would have been used to parse it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the values that are matching on the second query and not on the first, it's hard to be absolutely certain.  But one thing to keep in mind is that a time zone is not the same as an offset.  Please read "TimeZone != Offset" section of [the TimeZone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

For example, you say you are converting to the `America/New_York` time zone.  This zone is sometimes in UTC-05:00 (for Eastern Standard Time), and sometimes in UTC-04:00 (for Eastern Daylight Time).  It is entirely possible that some of your data is being picked up because of the -4 offset in effect during daylight savings time.

When you hardcode to the -5 offset, you are not taking any time zone rules into consideration.  Which would explain the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Timezone information is not applied to dates/times unless you either set ***useTimeZone=true*** in your connection URL. You can use the ***getTimestamp()*** method also, which take calendars as an argument.

Comment: Even then, it has no effect on how the time is stored. It only has an effect on how the time is displayed/parsed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Give this a try.**

Set timestamp parameter as you are setting now

```
pst.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(end.getTimeInMillis()));
```

.

During database call, JDBC driver may already be converting input date/time values to GMT. So the date value that database is dealing with won't have to take timezones of input date into considerations which may differ from one client to other.

Instead of setting **from_tz** as '+05:30'

```
convert_tz(updatedDate,'+05:30','-05:00')
```

Set **from_tz** as '00:00'

```
convert_tz(updatedDate,'00:00','-05:00')
```