# Convert timestamp in UTC to timestamptz

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

How do I convert a `timestamp` that is in UTC to `timestamptz`?

If my local time zone is GMT-1 and I run:

`select '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamptz`

I get:

`2017-01-01 00:00:00-01`

but I want:

`2017-01-01 01:00:00-01`

Comment: I know this is old but other people still see this... if you are GMT-1 it means you are shifted westwards, and hours are 1 BEHIND the UTC hour (less, so to speak). So shouldn't your expected output be 2016-12-31 23:00:00-01?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Better:

```
SELECT timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

No additional cast after the `AT TIME ZONE` construct. It returns `timestamp with time zone` (= `timestamptz`) for `timestamp without time zone` (= `timestamp`) input and vice versa.

For the given example, the shortest, most efficient way to provide a timestamp constant is `timestamp '2017-01-01'`. Or use a cast, almost as good: `'2017-01-01'::timestamp`. The time component `00:00:00` is assumed when missing.

There is no such thing as a *"timestamp that is in UTC"*. A `timestamp` carries no time zone information. Only you know that it's ***supposed*** to be located in the UTC time zone.

The type name "timestamp with time zone" is a bit misleading. `timestamptz` does not carry any time zone information, either. The given time zone name, abbreviation or offset is used to compute the corresponding UTC time. Text output (display) is adapted to the current time zone setting of your session. Only the bare value of the corresponding UTC time is stored. The time zone itself is never stored. If you need it, store it additionally in another column. In your particular case, UTC *happens* to be the time zone used for input as well.

Detailed explanation:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-postgresql-timestamps/28876266#28876266)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `select ('2017-01-01 00:00:00' at time zone 'utc')::timestamptz`

Comment: This actually shifts the time the wrong way. (As @Christoph pointed out, the example in the question, `2017-01-01 00:00:00` at UTC, i.e. `2017-01-01T00:00:00Z`, is actually `2016-12-31 23:00:00-01`)