# Will an existing timestamp without time zone value ever automatically change?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

For example, certain time values might auto change when the system time zone changes. Will a `timestamp without time zone` value that's already stored in the database auto change for any reason at all?

Comment: A database is used to store facts. Even if they are wrong. They wont change, though.

Answer (score 0):

Neither [`timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) nor [`timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *values* will ***ever*** change by themselves. Only the *display* of `timestamptz` adapts to the current [timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) setting.

Or you can display date and time for a given time zone with the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct. And / or you can format it any way you like with various [formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).

The actual setting in your session is relevant for display, not the system time zone. Related:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)