# Easiest way to convert YYYYMMDD to the midnight with specific timezone on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, timezone, sql-timestamp

I get the dates in a `YYYYMMDD` format.
I need to convert this column to the timestamp with specific timezone. What is the best/easiest way to do that?

So if I have `20210101` I want to get `2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000` in my TZ.

Comment: [to_char(your_timestamp_column AT TIME ZONE 'MST', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html) You can swap out 'MST' for your [desired timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

Comment: `dates in a YYYYMMDD format` dates have no format, they're binary data. PostgreSQL [has a proper date type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) that's only 4 bytes, far smaller than the 8 bytes used by that *string*. Use the correct data type. If you had a real date you'd only need to use `mydate AT TIME ZONE ...`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good point. What I suggested returns desired output specified in the question, but most likely it is in fact the case that they want to parse `text` type date to proper `date` type, specifying timestamp upon import. My function would come in later, when they wish to get it back in that specified format.

Comment: Assuming the text can be parsed, or that it's in the format the developer assumes and not in `mmddyyyy` as someone asked for earlier today. There's no real benefit to storing dates as text and a *lot* of downsides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your request is an **oxymoron**:

> I want to get `2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000` in my TZ.

You show a `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`) literal, which is completely orthogonal to (and ignorant of) the concept of time zones.

But you want it *"in my TZ"*, which would imply to a `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`) value, where the corresponding literal includes a time offset like: `2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000+01`.

Since the format `YYYYMMDD` is unambiguous ISO format, you can cast to `date` or `timestamp` directly, safely. A cast to `timestamp` assumes the time component `00:00` automatically. Produces your desired `timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00'`.

```
SELECT '20211203'::timestamp;
```

If you want the result type `timestamp`, we are done here.

If you want the result type `timestamptz`, there is a quick-and-dirty shortcut:

```
SELECT '20211203'::timestamptz;
```

The current time zone setting is assumed for the type cast. **But** this introduces a dependency on a runtime settings. Notoriously unreliable, only advisable for situations where you can be certain of the current setting ...

The sure and generally advisable way is to define the target time zone with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct explicitly. Say, your timezone is 'Europe/Vienna':

```
SELECT '20211203'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna';
```

Use a [time zone ***name***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html). [Time zone abbreviations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-abbrevs.html) are treacherous for input conversion and may fail for daylight saving time (DST) or other bureaucratic nonsense. 'CET' (Central European Time) is appropriate for timestamps during "standard time". During DST periods, you'd have to use 'CEST' (Central European Summer Time).

<sub>DST is utter nonsense, but some countries, including the EU, still haven't managed to get rid of it.</sub>

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a6e56b4430a778f784149f7c8e814bb8)* - note that dbfiddle runs with time zone `GB` by default.

Now you have the `timestamptz` value representing the start of the day (00:00) in your given time zone. Don't be fooled by the ***display*** of `timestamptz` values. That's always adjusted to the current time zone setting, but it always represents that unique point in time, just with different ways to display it.

You do understand that the time zone itself is never stored in a `timestamptz` value, right? Even though `timestamp with time zone` *sounds* like it might. See:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)

To force a certain *display* use `to_char()` or some other functions to generate the desired string. There is a dedicated page [*Data Type Formatting Functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) in the manual.

Related:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 1):

This is a conversion to `timestamp with time zone`. You can format it to whatever text representation you wish. My timezone is East European Time, EET (GMT + 2), so

```sql
select to_date('20211203', 'YYYYMMDD')::timestamp at time zone 'EET';
-- 2021-12-03 00:00:00.000 +0200
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. 
I'm on UCT (my DB settings), and executing your code I get:

'2021-12-02 22:00:00.000000 +00:00'

But what I want to get is always midnight, no matter which Zone I'm converting to. 
I want to get exactly what you did get:

'-- 2021-12-03 00:00:00.000 +0200'

Comment: Can you give me an example pls.

Comment: @botafogo Check your `datestyle` and `timezone` settings. If you wish to see timestamps in `EET` for some reason, use `set timezone='EET';` and try that query again. In case you need it, `to_char()` equivalent for reading in that specific format later is `select to_char(your_timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US TZHTZM');`

Comment: @botafogo Two things appeared to me. First, you might be mislead in thinking that "+0200" is a part of what you're saving to the database - it's actually only added on output as part of the format. Second, you might confuse what that `+0200` is: it does not come from the timestamp itself saying "this timestamp comes from a zone +2h away", it's just added to indicate "as seen in time zone shifted +2h0min from UTC".

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to assume that timestamps can be formatted on write and that they retain time zone information. They can't and they don't, which splits the problem in two:

### 1: How to interpret text-based timestamps.

```sql
create table test_timestamps as 
select ('20211203'||'Japan')::timestamptz as "your_timestamp";
```

PostgreSQL saves that in [binary format in `UTC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html#:%7E:text=For%20timestamp%20with%20time%20zone%2C%20the,the%20offset%20for%20the%20timezone%20zone.) so the entire idea of formatting and time zone doesn't apply to a stored `timestamp` type data. It's only formatted on read and converted to a different time zone if required.

### 2: How to get them in a specific format on read.

```sql
select to_char(
         "your_timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US TZHTZM') 
from test_timestamps;
```

where `at time zone` is only necessary if you want it to return the timestamp as observed elsewhere.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The results of your `select`s do depend on `TimeZone` setting. You can see the author getting `2021-12-02 22:00:00.000000 +00:00` while the other got `2021-12-03 00:00:00.000 +0200`. If all you do is execute the expression in psql or PGAdmin, it effectively displays the result, not only compute it - you'll find I referred to their specific context when using that word as well as 'depending'. If you state what is backwards in my answer, I'll be glad to correct it - after all, this is an attempt to clarify things for both myself and others.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I already clarified I had referred to a `select` issued in a repl as a means to get a value displayed. The part about my understanding of how `at time zone` works is your assumption about things I did not state nor imply - I encourage you to explain what gave you that impression, and I don't see why I shouldn't edit my answer accordingly. The last sentence is correct; if you want get the timestamp in the format requested by the author, you don't need `at time zone` in the query proposed, unless you wish to get it converted to another time zone. Among **what** "others"?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't think it was, but now you certainly did lead it there, especially after deleting your comments. Know that I edited my answer to swap out "displays" for "returns" for clarity, just in case. I'm genuinely thankful for the time you spent on your answers and your critique of mine, and wish you a nice day as well.

Answer (score -1):

To keep from over complicating  things:

```
create table dt_test (id integer, ts_fld timestamp, tsz_fld timestamp with time zone);

insert into dt_test values (1, '20211203'::date, '20211203'::date);

 select * from dt_test ;
 id |       ts_fld        |        tsz_fld         
----+---------------------+------------------------
  1 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00-08
```

A `date` will be taken as Midnight for timestamp purposes. So either just use it as `date` knowing it will be Midnight or do the explicit cast:

```
select '20211203'::date::timestamp, '20211203'::date::timestamptz;
      timestamp      |      timestamptz       
---------------------+------------------------
 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00-08

--Which can be shortened to:

select '20211203'::timestamp, '20211203'::timestamptz;
      timestamp      |      timestamptz       
---------------------+------------------------
 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00-08
```

Depending on whether you want to retain the time zone offset or not. For portability `2021-12-03 00:00:00-08` would be the better choice.