timestamp Vs timestamptz in database postgres
While creating backend of the systems i always store time in UTC that is when client side send any date time, i restrict to only accept UTC date time, the client side convert his local date time into UTC and then send it over the network using API.
I then store that utc date time into the database, i never cared about timezone. Then when the user ask for date time, i give them the UTC time which i stored, and then they convert it back to local time zone, this looks great to me.
My questions are,

Why i need to store time zone in the database ?
what is the real world use case where i need to store time zone as well, instead of just reallying on UTC ?
Any resource i can explore which can explain me in detail when to use which approach ?


Seems like another case of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28872761/939860

@ErwinBrandstetter my question is related to how will we be using this data type, like a real world use case for it?

The naming for those types is confusing. The type timestamptz does not store time zones in the database. It only means “I will accept time zone in the input and convert to UTC in storage” and “when you request I will return the UTC data converted to the set time zone.”
The documentation explains this in the timestamp part, but the table at the top really doesn’t say it clearly at all and this is a common confusion.
So neither can be used to store actual time zone information at all.
As for when you would need to store time zones, calendar applications are one big thing. Imagine you have an appointment at 14 on every Tuesday in a location with daylight savings. How do you know what is 14 every Tuesday unless you say the time zone and can convert correctly to other time zones when necessary? Just saving UTC would mean it’s off half the year.
Which to use? timestamptz is often recommended, for example Npgsql library states that as the best way. It sounds weird since “I just want UTC without time zones” but that’s exactly what that type brings - regardless of the naming.

if i have calendar application i will schedule appointments using UTC, so the appointment date and time will be in utc and then on the client side i convert it to client local time zone using javascript. I don't know any use case where i need this timestamptz except that when for some reason i wanna handle time conversion on backend, i wanna know what are those reasons ?

Actually timestamptz does store timezone, but just one UTC.

@JamalAhmed Like I mentioned, if I want to have a recurring meeting at 14 every Monday and you go “ok that’s 11 in UTC today”, how will you know how to convert back when daylight savings time changes? How will you know if daylight savings happens? Or when if it does? That’s impossible without storing the time zone for the event.

@SamiKuhmonen if i handle it this way, what i know till now is that, it will convert the date time based on postgres database time zone, how do we handle the flow? like what will the format of datetime the client side be sending over the api, and then how will i be returning him the date time?
