# Set timezone in spring quartz scheduled tasks annotation

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-annotations

I have a scheduled.xml spring file with entries like:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduled ref="calculateDailyFeesJob" method="sendMessage" cron="0 0 21 * * *" zone=""/>
    <task:scheduled ref="createInvoicesJob" method="sendMessage" cron="0 0 22 * * SUN"/>
```

How do I set the timezone?

Comment: You can set timezones on schedulers when creating them programatically. Like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273917/java-quartz-scheduler-across-timezone. I think you will have to move from XML config to Java Config.