# Backend Reminder Services Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, reminders

We would like to implement a reminder feature in our services where we have both Android and IOS application.

User using our mobile application set a reminder to notify on exact time periodically
Fox Example :
Set Remainder to feed a food for pets exactly on 10:30 AM every day.

Here User may login with different mobiles using same account  and need to notify them thru push notifications for all their mobile applications. We are using FCM to send push notifications as of now.

Once user set the reminder we have to store it in our backend DB (MYSQL) And on specific exact time Say (Every day 10 :30 AM) our backend services should know trigger the push notifications.

Currently we are using Spring Boot in our backend services . I have searched thru the web and some articles saying we can use "quartz" . Is there any third party application is available that can trigger the reminder or we can implement it on our own ?

We are thinking of the following workflow

User set reminder > Store it in DB > Spring Boot Application check for Reminder > Trigger the Notifications on exact time .

It would be grateful to us if any one provide the suggestions to implement this feature .

Thanks,

Comment: "*I have searched thru the web and some articles saying we can use "quartz" . Is there any third party application is available that can trigger the reminder or we can implement it on our own ?*" - Quartz does trigger the job automatically at the specified time once a job is persisted to the database.

Comment: @Turing85. Thanks . Is quartz works on different time zone ? Mean depends upon the user time zone reminders should be triggered.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273917/java-quartz-scheduler-across-timezone). Also, please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)